# function inside javascript loop only executes once

Tags: javascript, for-loop

this might be really obvious, but I'm a complete coding beginner...
can somebody tell me why this only executes the function with main(5)? And how could I change it so that main(2) executes after main(1), etc? Thanks!

```
for (var k = 1; k < 6; k++){
  main(k);
}
```

edit: sorry, this is the definition of main! I'm trying to animate a bunch of squares using a canvas

```
var main = function (speed) {
    Enemy.prototype.update = function () {
        var tx = 650 - this.x;
        var ty = 250 - this.y;
        var dist = Math.sqrt(tx * tx + ty * ty);
        this.velx = (tx / dist) * speed;
        this.vely = (ty / dist) * speed;

        if (dist > 0) {
            this.x += this.velx;
            this.y += this.vely;
        }
    };

    Enemy.prototype.isOnEnemy = function (x, y) {
        return (x >= this.x && x < this.x + 25 && // 25 = width
        y >= this.y && y < this.y + 25); // 25 = height
    };

    Enemy.prototype.render = function () {
        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + this.transparency + ')';
        context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 25, 25);
    };

    var enemies = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // random numbers from 0 (inclusive) to 100 (exclusive) for example:
        var randomX = Math.random() * 896;
        var randomY = Math.random() * 1303;
        console.log(randomX);
        console.log(randomY);
        if (randomX > 100 && randomX < 1200) {
            if (randomX % 2 === 0) {
                randomX = 140;
            } else {
                randomX = 1281;
            }
        }
        if (randomY > 100 && randomY < 75) {
            if (randomY % 2 === 0) {
                randomY = 15;
            } else {
                randomY = 560;
            }
        }
        var enemy = new Enemy(randomX, randomY, 0, 0, 1);
        enemies.push(enemy);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        // random numbers from 0 (inclusive) to 100 (exclusive) for example:
        var randomX = Math.random() * 200;
        var randomY = Math.random() * 403;
        console.log(randomX);
        console.log(randomY);
        if (randomX > 100 && randomX < 1200) {
            if (randomX % 2 === 0) {
                randomX = 140;
            } else {
                randomX = 1281;
            }
        }
        if (randomY > 100 && randomY < 75) {
            if (randomY % 2 === 0) {
                randomY = 15;
            } else {
                randomY = 560;
            }
        }
        var enemy = new Enemy(randomX, randomY, 0, 0, 1);
        enemies.push(enemy);
    }

    context.canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
        var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
            x = e.clientX - rect.left,
            y = e.clientY - rect.top,
            i = 0;

        for (; i < enemies.length; i++) {
            if (enemies[i].isOnEnemy(x, y)) {
                enemies[i].transparency = 0;
            }
        }
    };

    function render() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
            var one = enemies[i];
            one.update();
            one.render();
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
    render();
};
```

Comment: I think you are doing some **async** task in `main` function, can you post the definition of `main`?

Comment: That's a proper loop. It will loop 5 times, and pass 1 - 5 as arguments to main(). Need more information. See: http://jsfiddle.net/2bpd002o/

Comment: Even if all instructions inside the function main are defered, with that loop, main will be properly called with each values of k.

Comment: `Enemy.prototype` can only retain 1 each of `update`, `isOnEnemy`, etc. Each call to `main()` is redefining these, overriding and discarding any previous definitions, affecting all existing `new Enemy()` instances. And, the last set of them knows `speed` to be `5`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure how prototype works :/ Is there a way to do what I want without changing the way I implement the rest of my code?

Comment: Move the prototype stuff out of the `main` loop function to the scope above it so it doesn't get executed more than once. More info on prototypes: [Understanding “Prototypes” in JavaScript](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the definitions for `Enemy.prototype.update`, etc.

Each call to `main()` is defining these, but the `prototype` can only retain 1 of each. So, after the first, each call to `main()` discards and overrides the previous definitions.

The `Enemy.prototype` is the object that each `new Enemy()` inherits from (ref: [MDN: Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)). This makes it useful for shared properties and methods that don't change from one instance to another.

Since the `speed` is the only change, you can likely have the instances keep their own value, allowing the methods to be the same for all of them. Also allowing you define them once outside of `main()`.

```
Enemy.prototype.update = function () {
    // ...
    this.velx = (tx / dist) * this.speed; // <---
    this.vely = (ty / dist) * this.speed; // <---
    // ...
};

// ...

var main = function (speed) {
    // ...
        var enemy = new Enemy(randomX, randomY, 0, 0, 1);
        enemy.speed = speed; // <---
        enemies.push(enemy);
    // ...
};
```

If you can modify other code slightly ("*without changing the way I implement the rest of my code*"), you can modify the constructor to accept and assign the `speed`:

```
function Enemy(speed, x, y, ...) {
    this.speed = speed;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    // ...
}
```

```
var enemy = new Enemy(speed, randomX, randomY, 0, 0, 1);
enemies.push(enemy);
```

Comment: thanks! That actually makes a lot of sense to me; when I change it though, it's still the same problem... did I make a mistake in my code? http://jsfiddle.net/01hcbd9v/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a closure in an immediately invoked function to preserve the value that is sent to `main`...

```
for (var k = 1; k < 6; k++){
  (function(i) {
    main(i);
  })(k);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's still the same problem :/ it's only running once with main(5)

Comment: Yeah, I can see that now.  check out the comment by @JonathanLonowski  above for a better solution...